# Searching for a boolean type field from mongo via angular formly

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, angular-formly

I got to implement a simple search (or it was that to my mind), the field I'm searching for is called "paymentStatus" on an Invoice and it's basically a boolean value in a mongo db (v3.4). The search comes from angular-formly input field (angularJS 1.6), and I can see it logged quite easily , as "paymentStatus - true", and "paymentStatus-false" when I send the info to search for -

```
{ paymentStatus: true }
```

Formly field looks like this -

```
{
                        key: 'paymentStatus',
                        type: 'horizontal-ui-select',
                        className: 'tooltipLabel',
                        templateOptions: {
                            optionsAttr: 'bs-options',
                            ngOptions: 'option[to.valueProp] as option in to.options | filter: $select.search',
                            label: $filter('translate')('Payment Status'), 
                            placeholder: $filter('translate')('Payment Status'),
                            valueProp: 'paymentStatus',
                            labelProp: 'name',
                            searchable: true,
                            tooltipClass: 'wide-tooltip',
                            options: [
                                {"paymentStatus": true, "name": 'Paid'},
                                {"paymentStatus": false, "name": 'Unpaid'},
                            ]
                        } 

                    },
```

In the controller for backend to fill up the table with data to be displayed (which works correctly),
I have additional code for search filter which is like this -

```
if (where.paymentStatus && where.paymentStatus !== null && where.paymentStatus !== undefined) {
            mongoQuery[0].$match["$and"].push({"paymentStatus": {$in: where.paymentStatus}});
        }
```

I tried playing with $eq instead of $in and basic true false toggles instead of "where.paymentStatus" which give me half result half the time. "where" is from request.allParams().data.where. I'm a beginner with DB work/searches, especially with mongo and angular JS formly. It's legacy code that's sparsely documented. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, `where.paymentStatus` annuled my querying for false status. Replaced $in with $eq also. Works properly now.